# Delete files from one folder if a similarly named file does not exist in another folder

Tags: windows-7, batch, file-management

I need to delete files from folder A if a file with the *same name but different file type* does not exist in folder B.

For example:

```
FOLDER A
file1.gif
file2.gif
file3.gif
file4.gif
file5.gif
file6.gif

FOLDER B
file2.jpg
file4.jpg
file6.jpg
```

The batch file or software would compare the two folders and delete `file1.gif`, `file3.gif` and `file5.gif` from folder A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this directly from command line:
`for %F in ("A\*.gif") do @if not exist "B\%~nF.jpg" echo del "%F"`
Above example simply ***prints*** the commands so you can verify it will does what you want. After you're sure it's ok remove `echo` and it will actually run `delete`.
You may of course put this in a batch, if you wish so replace `%` with `%%` and remove `@` (and probably add `@echo off` instead)

Comment: This worked perfectly - I wish I could vote twice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also works if you want to delete files from A that EXIST in B:
```for %F in ("A\*.gif") do @if exist "B\%~nF.jpg" echo del "%F"```